# To add all values from the same column in each row of a mysqli SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a statement like below in which I need to add all of the invoice totals at the end of the table. My boss wants to know the months totals from all invoices.

```
$r = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE parent_id = '0' ");

while ($row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' .  $row['invoice_total'] . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
  echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You can use `SUM()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum - http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$r = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE parent_id = '0' ");
$sum = 0;
while ($row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' .  $row['invoice_total'] . '</td>';
  $sum = $sum + $row['invoice_total'];
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '$sum';
```